# Bar plot, no space between bottom of geom and x axis keep space above

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

When I plot a bar graph in ggplot2 I would like to reduce the space between the bottom of the bars and the x-axis to 0, yet keep the space above the bars and the plot box.  I have a hack to do it below.  It's dirty and I want to be clean again.  Is there a way to achieve this behavior without the dirty little hack?

**Default (desired space above but don't want space below bars):**

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=as.factor(carb))) + 
    geom_bar()
```

[image]

**Use expand (undesired 0 space above but got the 0 space below bars):**

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=as.factor(carb))) + 
    geom_bar() + 
    scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0))
```

[image]

**Dirty Hack (I like it but its.. well, dirty):**

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=as.factor(carb))) + 
    geom_bar() + 
    scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0)) +
    geom_text(aes(x=1, y=10.3, label="Stretch it"), vjust=-1)
```

[image]

Comment: I assume you consider using `coord_cartesian` to much hardcoding as well?

Comment: @baptise can you add as a solution for future searchers.  That works as well.

Comment: Good question, this also annoys me in ggplot2 graphs that y axis does not start from the bottom of the picture frame.

Comment: There's a new(er) question that points back to this one, with a [really great solution](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22480052/903061) generalizing the `expand()` into a list of upper limit expansion and lower limit expansion.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The R documentation includes a new convenience function called `expansion` for the `expand` argument as the `expand_scale()` became deprecated as of [ggplot2 v3.3.0 release](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/blob/master/NEWS.md#minor-improvements-and-bug-fixes).

```
ggplot(mtcars) +
  geom_bar(aes(x = factor(carb))) + 
  scale_y_continuous(expand = expansion(mult = c(0, .1)))
```

Comment: This is the correct answer and should receive the checkmark.

Comment: The trick is to use the expansion combined .1 which is not said by many answers that I've lookup

Answer (score 50):

I might be missing what you really want, but without using `geom_text` hack you can still set the limits

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = as.factor(carb))) + 
    geom_bar() + 
    scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0), limits = c(0, 10.3)) 

# marginally cleaner
```

Comment: Yes exactly what I wanted.  I tried to use: `ylim(c(0,10.3))` after the `scale_y_continuous` and it was a no go.  I get it now.  Pretty simple.  Thanks.

Comment: I removed the check and awarded to a better answer at this time.  I awared a bounty to your answer so no points were lost.  Thank you.  Your original solution was very useful until it was addressed by the ggplot2 team.

Answer (score 19):

You can expand the limits manually, e.g. with `expand_limits(y=10.1)`, or use this trick to add an invisible layer with scaled up data,

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=as.factor(carb))) + 
    geom_bar() + 
    scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0)) +
    geom_blank(aes(y=1.1*..count..), stat="bin")
```

Comment: Ahaa, those `..` variables...+1!

Comment: Is there a way to do this without hard coding (1.1)?

Comment: I mean that this multiplication by 1.1 works in this case but if you have dynamically changing y-axis and you do not know the scale beforehand. In these kind of cases you somehow have to use a parameter instead of hardcoding this multiplication factor. It would be nice if ggplot could do this automatically based on data (y axis scale).

Comment: i still don't understand - the `..count..` variable takes care of this automatic adjustment of the y-axis, but at some point it is up to the user to define what margin should be added above the bar (here 10% of the full data range) and that's what this multiplication factor does. It's the same with default axes in base R and ggplot2.

Answer (score 15):

Starting in **ggplot2 3.0.0** there is an `expand_scale()` function that can be used with the `expand` argument to do exactly this.  You define the top and bottom expansion separately.

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=factor(carb))) + 
     geom_bar() +
     scale_y_continuous(expand = expand_scale(mult = c(0, .1)))
```

Answer (score 9):

Because you seem comfortable with some hardcoding...

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = as.factor(carb))) + 
  geom_bar() +
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0, 10.3))
```

Comment: I didn't realize before how powerful this answer can be and generalizable to categorical scales as well.

Answer (score 4):

This is an automatic way to produce the spacing at the top, yet remove the bottom spacing. I use 3 % padding since that's what you hard-coded.

```
plot1 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=as.factor(carb))) +
    geom_bar()

plotInfo <- print(plot1)
yMax <- max(plotInfo$data[[1]]$ymax)
yLimitMax <- 1.03 * yMax

plot2 <- plot1 +
    scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0),
                       limits = c(0,yLimitMax))
```

If you want to remove the three lines between the plots, just write this in `plot2` instead:

```
limits = c(0, 1.03 * max(print(plot1)$data[[1]]$ymax))
```