# How to expand axis asymmetrically with ggplot2 without setting limits manually?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want the bottom axis for a barplot to be zero, but top expanded by a small amount (according to some scale). However, I am plotting the output of `stat_summary` so I do not have the maximum value available to me, and I am using facets with `scale="free_y"` so I cannot manually set them. Otherwise I would use [baptiste's trick of adding `geom_blank`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20220424/ggplot2-bar-plot-no-space-between-bottom-of-geom-and-x-axis-keep-space-above). I know I could read off the values and create a data frame with upper bounds manually, but can this be set without having to hard-code the limits?

The other option is to compute the means outside of the function call and just plot that without calling `stat_summary` (this way I have the upper bounds directly for each facet), but is there any way around this?

Example:

```
ggplot(mtcars)+
  stat_summary(aes(cyl,mpg),
               fun.y="mean",
               geom="bar")+
  scale_y_continuous(expand=c(0,0))+
  facet_grid(carb~.,"free_y")
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can "extend" ggplot by creating a scale with a custom class and implementing the internal S3 method scale_dimension like so:

```
library("scales")
scale_dimension.custom_expand <- function(scale, expand = ggplot2:::scale_expand(scale)) {
  expand_range(ggplot2:::scale_limits(scale), expand[[1]], expand[[2]])
}

scale_y_continuous <- function(...) {
  s <- ggplot2::scale_y_continuous(...)
  class(s) <- c('custom_expand', class(s))
  s
}
```

This is also an example of overriding the default scale. Now, to get the desired result you specify expand like so

```
qplot(1:10, 1:10) + scale_y_continuous(expand=list(c(0,0.1), c(0,0)))
```

where the first vector in the list is the multiplicative factor, the second is the additive part and the first (second) element of each vector corresponds to lower (upper) boundary.

Comment: It doesn't work for me, with version 2.0.0 of ggplot. I get `Error in diff(range) * mul : non-numeric argument to binary operator`

Comment: @YvanR For a `ggplot2` v2 solution, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34623780/asymmetric-expansion-of-limits-ggplot2-2-0 (there is currently a pull request for adding support for asymmetrical range expansion).