# Pad (expand) only the top of continuous scale in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've got some data that share a common x-axis but have two different y variables:

```
set.seed(42)
data = data.frame(
    x = rep(2000:2004, 2),
    y = c(rnorm(5, 20, 5), rnorm(5, 150, 15)),
    var = rep(c("A", "B"), each = 5)
)
```

I'm using a faceted line plot to display the data:

```
p = ggplot(data, aes(x, y)) +
    geom_line() +
    facet_grid(var ~ ., scales = "free_y")
```

[image]

I'd like the y-axis to include 0. This is easy enough:

```
p + expand_limits(y = 0)
```

but then my data looks crowded too close to the top of my facets. So I'd like to pad the range of the axis. Normally `scale_y_continuous(expand = ...)` is used for padding the axis, but the padding is applied symmetrically to the top and bottom, making the y-axis go well *below* 0.

```
p + expand_limits(y = 0) + 
    scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0.3, 0.2))
# the order of expand_limits and scale_y_continuous
# does not change the output
```

[image]

I can't explicitly set limits because of the facets with free y scales. **What's the best way to have the y-scale extend down to 0  (not below!), while multiplicatively padding the top of the y scale?**

Comment: Have a look at @Rosen Matev's asymmetric padding function at [how to expand axis asymmetrically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22480052/how-to-expand-axis-asymmetrically-with-ggplot2-without-setting-limits-manually)

Comment: @SandyMuspratt thanks! That's exactly what I'm looking for. Also a dupe.

Comment: Rosen Matev's solution broke with ggplot 2.0. I offer a really clunky solution [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34623780/asymmetric-expansion-of-limits-ggplot2-2-0/37695022#37695022).

Answer (score 3):

You could create an extra data set with a single point for each facet and plot it invisibly with `geom_blank()`. The point is chosen to be a fixed factor larger than the maximum value in the given facet. Here, I choose that factor to be 1.5 to make the  effect clearly visible:

```
max_data <- aggregate(y ~ var, data = data, FUN = function(y) max(y) * 1.5)
max_data <- transform(max_data, x = 2000)

p + geom_blank(data = max_data)
```

And this is what I get:

[image]

Comment: This works well (+1!) but I'm optimistically hoping for something that could be added to a plot - I'd love it if I could incorporate this behavior as part of a theme.