# Asymmetric expansion of ggplot axis limits

Tags: r, ggplot2

How do you adjust the expansion of limits asymmetrically in ggplot? For example,

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mtcars) + 
  geom_bar(aes(x = cyl), width = 1)
```

[image]

I would like the bottom of the bars flush with the bottom of the panel background, but would still like space at the top. I can achieve this with a blank annotation:

```
ggplot(mtcars) + 
  geom_bar(aes(x = cyl), width = 1) +
  annotate("blank", x = 4, y = 16) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0.0,0))
```

[image]

In previous versions of `ggplot`, however, I could use [the solution provided by Rosen Matev](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22480052/how-to-expand-axis-asymmetrically-with-ggplot2-without-setting-limits-manually):

```
library("scales")
scale_dimension.custom_expand <- function(scale, expand = ggplot2:::scale_expand(scale)) {
  expand_range(ggplot2:::scale_limits(scale), expand[[1]], expand[[2]])
}

scale_y_continuous <- function(...) {
  s <- ggplot2::scale_y_continuous(...)
  class(s) <- c('custom_expand', class(s))
  s
}
```

and then use `scale_y_continuous(expand = list(c(0,0.1), c(0,0)))` which would add a consistently addition to the top of the chart. In the current version, however, I get an error

```
ggplot(mtcars) + 
  geom_bar(aes(x = cyl), width = 1) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = list(c(0,0.1), c(0,0)))

# Error in diff(range) * mul : non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

Is there an effective solution for ggplot2 2.0?

A solution should include the ability to work flexibly with facets, and `free_xy` scale options. For example,

```
ggplot(mtcars) + 
  geom_bar(aes(x = cyl, fill = factor(vs)), width = 1) + 
  facet_grid(vs ~ ., scales = "free_y")
```

[image]

A solution should provide something like:

```
ggplot(mtcars) + 
  geom_bar(aes(x = cyl, fill = factor(vs)), width = 1) + 
  facet_grid(vs ~ ., scales = "free_y") + 
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0)) + 
  geom_blank(data = data.frame(cyl = c(5,5), y = c(12, 16), vs = c(1,0)), aes(x = cyl, y = y))
```

[image]

Comment: For maximum flexibility I'd suggest making the example in your question use facets. For an unfaceted plot it's possible to aggregate your data and use `ylim = c(0, 1.1 * max(aggregated_data$y_variable))` - though not nearly as nice as the modified expand solution. With a faceted plot, the `ylim` solution won't work well, so an `expand` type solution is *required*.

Comment: In the unfaceted case, couldn't you use `coord_cartesian` to get the effect you want? For example: `coord_cartesian(ylim=c(0, max(table(mtcars$cyl))+2), xlim=c(min(mtcars$cyl)-0.75, max(mtcars$cyl)+0.75), expand=FALSE)`. Before version 2.0, it wasn't necessary to set `xlim`, but (as far as I can tell) now that the default is `expand=TRUE` you need to set both limits explicitly if you want to keep the padding on the x-axis.

Comment: @eipi10 is making my point. In the non-faceted case you can find workarounds fairly easily. The answer *I'm* interested in (and I think Hugh is too) is one that works both with and without facets.

Comment: Hugh, if you're amenable to an edit to include facets, I'd be happy to post a bounty on the question when it becomes eligible - I'm very interested in finding a solution.

Comment: @Gregor although it would be nice to be able to set custom y-scales with facetting, another option would be a for loop (or lapply) to create one plot for each value of the faceting variable and then lay out the plots using grid.arrange (from the gridExtra package). Then you can set the y-range by facet. For example, if `gear` is the faceting variable (and we use `i` as the loop dummy variable), `coord_cartesian(ylim=c(0, max(table(mtcars$cyl[mtcars$gear==i]))+2), 
                    xlim=c(min(mtcars$cyl)-0.75, max(mtcars$cyl)+0.75), expand=FALSE)`

Comment: ...a painful workaround that's difficult to generalize. What about `facet_grid`? How about a *complicated* facet grid, `facet_grid(cyl + vs ~ am + gear)`? I'd like an elegant, flexible and generalizable solution, like the custom `scale_y_continuous`. Something that doesn't require copying and pasting and introducing bugs while I edit `table()` and `lapply()` commands.

Comment: @Gregor I've added a facet example. Not sure if what's been requested is adequate for your bounty purposes. Feel free to suggest an edit if you need more. I went with something fairly simple, but with a note that the solution should be 'flexible'.

Comment: Questions aren't eligible for bounties until they've been open for 48 hours. I might wait until the weekend so I can take a good stab at it myself first.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

[`ggplot2 v3.0.0`](https://www.tidyverse.org/articles/2018/07/ggplot2-3-0-0/) released in July 2018 has [`expand_scale()`](https://rdrr.io/github/hadley/ggplot2/man/expand_scale.html) option (w/ `mult` argument) to achieve OP's goal.

Edit: `expand_scale()` will be deprecated in the future release in favor of `expansion()`. See [News](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/blob/master/NEWS.md) for more information.

```
library(ggplot2)

### ggplot <= 3.2.1
ggplot(mtcars) + 
  geom_bar(aes(x = cyl, fill = factor(vs)), width = 1) + 
  facet_grid(vs ~ ., scales = "free_y") + 
  scale_y_continuous(expand = expand_scale(mult = c(0, .2))) 

### ggplot >= 3.2.1.9000
ggplot(mtcars) + 
  geom_bar(aes(x = cyl, fill = factor(vs)), width = 1) + 
  facet_grid(vs ~ ., scales = "free_y") + 
  scale_y_continuous(expand = expansion(mult = c(0, .2)))
```

[image]

Comment: +1 for saving me the hours it would have taken to add dummy dataframes to my plot to manually change all the axes... to think of all of the time I spent doing this in the past!!

Answer (score 9):

I have now tried to add code for this to `ggplot2`; see [issue #1669](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/issues/1669) and the [corresponding pull request](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/pull/1670). If it is accepted, the syntax for the `expand` argument will been changed from `c(m, a)` to `c(m_lower, a_lower, m_uppper, a_upper)`, for specifying separate expansion values for the lower and upper range limits. (The old syntax will still continue to work, though, as the first two elements will be reused if elements three and/or four are missing.)

With this new syntax, you can use

```
ggplot(mtcars) +
  geom_bar(aes(x = cyl), width = 1) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0, 0.05, 0))
```

The result looks like this:

[image: Simple bar chart]

It also works with facetting:

```
ggplot(mtcars) +
  geom_bar(aes(x = cyl, fill = factor(vs)), width = 1) +
  facet_grid(vs ~ ., scales = "free_y") +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0, 0.05, 0))
```

[image: Bar chart with facetting]

Comment: what happend with the implementation?

Answer (score 2):

I used Rosen Matev's solution often, and was disappointed when it broke with ggplot version 2.0. I offer a solution, though not nearly as elegant as Rosen's, but will work on plots with no facetting, `facet_wrap`, and `facet_grid`, and with one-way and two-way `facet_grid`. However, it will not work with more complicated facet grids, nor will it work with `coord_flip`. There are two functions: one for asymmetric expansion along the y-axis, and one for expansion along the x-axis. The functions perform multiplicative and additive expansions.

The functions gather information from the plot, calculate new limits for the y (or x) axis, then use `geom_blank` to construct new plots with the desired expansion factors.

First, a function to perform asymmetric expansion along the y-axis.

```
# Function takes two parameters
#   'p' is the plot
#   'expand' is a list of two vectors:
#     First vector contains the multiplicative factors;
#     Second vector contains the additive parts.
#       First element in each vector refers to the lower boundary;
#       Second element refers to the upper boundary.

asymmY = function(p, expand = list(mult = c(0, .2), add = c(0, 0))) {

  np = p + coord_cartesian(expand = FALSE)  # No expand
  gb <- ggplot_build(np)

  limits <- sapply(gb$panel$ranges, "[[", "y.range")
  range = apply(limits, 2, function(x) max(x) - min(x))
  rangeU = range*expand[[1]][2]
  rangeL = range*expand[[1]][1]
  limits <- limits + rbind(-rangeL, rangeU)  # Multiplicative expand

  limits[1,] = limits[1,] - expand[[2]][1]   # Additive expand
  limits[2,] = limits[2,] + expand[[2]][2]   

  limits = as.vector(limits)

  df = facet_type(np, gb, "y", limits)  # df with new limits - depends on facet type

  np = np + geom_blank(data = df, inherit.aes = FALSE, aes(x = Inf, y = y)) # new plot

  # But the x axis expansions were set to false. Put back the default expand
  gb <- ggplot_build(np)

 if(any(grepl("Discrete", class(gb$panel$x_scale[[1]])))) {
    limits <- sapply(gb$panel$ranges, "[[", "x.range")
    limits[1,] = ceiling(limits[1,]) - .6
    limits[2,] = trunc(limits[2,]) + .6
    limits = as.vector(limits)
 } else {
    limits <- sapply(gb$panel$ranges, "[[", "x.range")
    range = apply(limits, 2, function(x) max(x) - min(x))
    rangeU = range*.05
    rangeL = range*.05
    limits <- limits + rbind(-rangeL, rangeU)
    limits = as.vector(limits)
 }

  df = facet_type(np, gb, "x", limits)

  np + geom_blank(data = df, inherit.aes = FALSE, aes(x = x, y = Inf))
}

# Function to determine type of facetting  
# and to get data frame of new limits.
facet_type = function(np, gb, axis, limits) {
    if(class(np$facet)[1] == "null") { 
      setNames(data.frame(y = limits), axis)
  } else 
    if(class(np$facet)[1] == "wrap") {
      facetvar <- as.character(np$facet$facets)
      facetlev <- gb$panel$layout[[facetvar]]
      setNames(data.frame(rep(facetlev, each = 2), limits), c(facetvar, axis))
  } else {
      facetvar <- as.character(np$facet$cols)
      if(length(facetvar) == 0) facetvar <- as.character(np$facet$rows)
      facetlev <- gb$panel$layout[[facetvar]]
      setNames(data.frame(rep(facetlev, each = 2), limits), c(facetvar, axis))
  }
}
```

Try it out with some facet wrap and facet grid plots.

```
# Try asymmetric expand along y-axis
library(ggplot2)

p1 <- ggplot(mtcars) + 
  geom_bar(aes(x = factor(cyl))) + 
  facet_grid(am  ~ vs , scales = "free_y")

p2 <- ggplot(mtcars) + 
  geom_bar(aes(x = factor(cyl), fill = factor(vs)), width = .5) + 
  facet_grid(vs ~ ., scales = "free_y") 

p3 <- ggplot(mtcars) + 
  geom_bar(aes(x = factor(cyl), fill = factor(vs)), width = .5) + 
  facet_grid(. ~ vs)

p4 <- ggplot(mtcars) + 
  geom_bar(aes(x = factor(cyl), fill = factor(vs)), width = .5) + 
  facet_wrap(~vs, scales = "free_y") 

asymmY(p1, list(c(0, 0.1), c(0, 0)))
asymmY(p2, list(c(0, 0.1), c(0, 0)))
asymmY(p3, list(c(0, 0.1), c(0, 0)))
asymmY(p4, list(c(0, 0.1), c(0, 0)))
```

Second, a function to perform asymmetric expansion along the x-axis.

```
asymmX = function(p, expand = list(mult = c(0, .2), add = c(0, 0))) {

  np = p + coord_cartesian(expand = FALSE)  # No expand
  gb <- ggplot_build(np)

  limits <- sapply(gb$panel$ranges, "[[", "x.range")
  range = apply(limits, 2, function(x) max(x) - min(x))
  rangeU = range*expand[[1]][2]
  rangeL = range*expand[[1]][1]
  limits <- limits + rbind(-rangeL, rangeU)  # Mult expand

  limits[1,] = limits[1,] - expand[[2]][1]
  limits[2,] = limits[2,] + expand[[2]][2]   # Add expand

  limits = as.vector(limits)

  df = facet_type(np, gb, "x", limits)  # df with new limits - depends on facet type

  np = np + geom_blank(data = df, inherit.aes = FALSE, aes(x = x, y = Inf)) # new plot

  # But the y axis expansions were set to false. Put back the default expand
  gb <- ggplot_build(np)

 if(any(grepl("Discrete", class(gb$panel$y_scale[[1]])))) {
    limits <- sapply(gb$panel$ranges, "[[", "y.range")
    limits[1,] = ceiling(limits[1,]) - .6
    limits[2,] = trunc(limits[2,]) + .6
    limits = as.vector(limits)
 } else {
    limits <- sapply(gb$panel$ranges, "[[", "y.range")
    range = apply(limits, 2, function(x) max(x) - min(x))
    rangeU = range*.05
    rangeL = range*.05
    limits <- limits + rbind(-rangeL, rangeU)
    limits = as.vector(limits)
 }

  df = facet_type(np, gb, "y", limits)

  np + geom_blank(data = df, inherit.aes = FALSE, aes(x = Inf, y = y))
}
```

Try it out.

```
# Try asymmetric expand along x-axis
df = data.frame(x = c(20, 15, 25, 23, 12, 14), 
                y = rep(c("a", "b", "c"), 2),
                z = rep(c("aaa", "bbb"), each = 3),
                w = rep(c("ccc", "ddd", "eee"), each = 2))

p1 = ggplot(df[,-4]) + geom_point(aes(x, y)) +
   geom_segment(aes(x = 0, xend = x, y = y, yend = y)) +
   geom_text(aes(x = x, y = y, label = x), hjust = -1) +
   facet_grid(. ~ z, scales = "free_x") 

p2 = ggplot(df[, -4]) + geom_point(aes(x, y)) +
   geom_segment(aes(x = 0, xend = x, y = y, yend = y)) +
   geom_text(aes(x = x, y = y, label = x), hjust = -1) +
   facet_grid(z ~ .)

p3 = ggplot(df) + geom_point(aes(x, y)) +
   geom_segment(aes(x = 0, xend = x, y = y, yend = y)) +
   geom_text(aes(x = x, y = y, label = x), hjust = -1) +
   facet_grid(w ~ z)

p4 = ggplot(df[,-4]) + geom_point(aes(x, y)) +
   geom_segment(aes(x = 0, xend = x, y = y, yend = y)) +
   geom_text(aes(x = x, y = y, label = x), hjust = -1) +
   facet_wrap(~ z)

asymmX(p1, list(c(0, .15), c(0, 0)))
asymmX(p2, list(c(0, 0), c(0, 5)))
asymmX(p3, list(c(0, .2), c(0, 0)))
asymmX(p4, list(c(0, 0), c(9, 5)))
```