# ggplot - geom_text with free scales facet_wrap

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following data:

```
thedata <-  data.frame(value= c(90,100,2,10)
                       ,category1 = c("A","A","B","B")
                       ,category2 = c("C","D","C","D"))
```

And I am looking to produce the following figure with labels just to the outside of the bars:

```
ggplot(thedata, aes(x=category2, y=value)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position="dodge", fill = "grey") +
  facet_wrap(~category1, scales = "free_x") +
  coord_flip() +
  geom_text(aes(label=value, hjust = -0.35))
```

[image]

Using this method the labels fall outside the chart range. If the `expand_limits` argument is used it overwrites the `scales = "free_x"` argument. Any suggestions for say, adding an extra 10% space to each of the chart to accommodate the labels?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `expand` argument of `scale_y_continuous`. See `?continuous_scale` for details.

Comment: To add space in just one direction see the new `expand_scale()` function (as of ggplot2 3.0.0).  You can see an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48678947/2461552).

Comment: Thanks, if I add argument `scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0.1, 0))` then that does the trick!