# Panel border won't fall on x-axis using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to add a panel border to my plot - but the border keeps falling somewhere below the x-axis.  Does anyone have any suggestions to have the bottom line of the panel border fall directly on the x-axis.

```
f<- ggplot(nadph, aes(x = reorder(DGRP.Line, MEN), y = MEN)) +
geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
xlab("DGRP Line") + ylab ("MEN activity (standardized)") +
theme(axis.text.x=element_blank(),
    panel.background = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
    axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),
    panel.border = element_rect(color = "black", fill= NA, size=1))
```

Comment: Please see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) for some examples of how to include a reproducible example in a question.  That will help others help you.

Comment: If you're trying to remove the space between the x axis and the bottom of the plot, see the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22945651/how-to-remove-space-between-axis-area-plot-in-ggplot2).  You may be interested in only removing that space and not the space on the top of the plot, in which case see the answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20220424/ggplot2-bar-plot-no-space-between-bottom-of-geom-and-x-axis-keep-space-above)