# Remove space at bottom of facet

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-grid

I'm working on a chart with #ggplot and facet but I'm not getting to the result I wish for.
With the code shown below I always get some space between labels and bars

Even adding *switch="y"* I can move the facet titles on the left but the space is still there even using *axis.ticks = element_blank()*.

Here the results I'm stick with
https://i.stack.imgur.com/uQV6f.jpg

EDIT
Thanks to @StéphaneLaurent I added the 
`scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0))`
parameter solving the gap problem, what I would do now is replace label with facet and viceversa

```
df=data.frame(
    CHANNEL=c("IN","IN","IN","OUT","OUT","OUT"),
    AGEING=c("A","B","C","A","B","C"),  
DELTA=c(4.84904880066170385,4.44191343963553464,3.32480818414322288,1.74081237911025144,1.86749666518452639,1.74672489082969418)
)
ggplot(df, aes(AGEING, DELTA, fill=CHANNEL)) +
    geom_bar(stat="identity") + coord_flip() +
    facet_grid(vars(CHANNEL), space = "free", switch="y") +
    theme(legend.position = "none",
        axis.ticks = element_blank(),
        axis.title.x = element_blank(),
        axis.title.y = element_blank()
        )
```

Comment: Is it what you mean: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20220424/ggplot2-bar-plot-no-space-between-bottom-of-geom-and-x-axis-keep-space-above ?

Comment: Thanks @StéphaneLaurent, the expand solved part of the problem removing the space between labels but I still don't know how to swap facet and labels

Comment: Please add more detail to your question. "I'm not getting to the result I wish for" doesn't make it very clear what you want. "I still don't know how to swap facet and labels" implies this was part of your question, but I don't see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On top of the `expand` option mentioned in the comments for your first issue, you can place the `facet labels` on the outside with `theme(strip.placement = "outside")`:

```
ggplot(df, aes(AGEING, DELTA, fill=CHANNEL)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity") + coord_flip() +
  facet_grid(vars(CHANNEL), space = "free", switch="y") +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0)) +
  theme(legend.position = "none",
        axis.ticks = element_blank(),
        axis.title.x = element_blank(),
        axis.title.y = element_blank()
  ) +
  theme(strip.placement = "outside")
```

Resulting in:[image]